# Accessing Data in Objects in Link Lists

Tags: c++, list, iterator

Ok say i have a list of objects and I have an iterator pointing at one of them. How do I access data out of the object.

Ive tried

```
*iterator_name.data
```

but that doesint seem to work. Any ideas

Comment: `it->data` or `(*it).data` (`iterator` is a terrible name for a variable, btw).

Comment: Thanks , its also not the name i just needed a quick example

Comment: This tutorial might help: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/iterators.html.  PS: I often use "the old way" the tutorial tells you to avoid; indexing list elements is still useful in many situations.  IMHO...